# What is the difference between Agent Oriented Programming and Reactive Programming?

Tags: reactive-programming, agent, paradigms

What is the difference between Agent Oriented Programming and Reactive Programming? Is Reactive Programming is just a subset of Agent-Oriented Programming?

Answer (score 0):

According Wooldridge's "An Introduction to MAS" (2002, 2009 2nd edition), agents should be a) reactive, b) proactive, and c) social. The biggest issue is to implemente the proactive trait. One of the models available for that is the BDI-Model (Beliefs, Desires, and Intentions), which should provide some autonomy to this agents – regarding that they must have their own threads.

On the other hand, you could easily implement a pure reactive agent. In this sense, I should say Reactive Programming is a subset of AOP.